# Ejecutar scripts Python desde Django

Tags: python, django, api, web, script

Llevo un tiempo trabajando en unos scripts en Python para realizar ciertas acciones y ahorrarme algo de tiempo en algunas tareas. Ahora que los tengo acabados me gustaría tener una pequeña aplicación web, la cual al realizarle ciertas peticiones Rest se activarán estos scripts y me devolviera en forma de respuesta la salida de la ejecución de estos. Para hacer esto, estoy trabajando con Django haciendo una API rest, pero ahora mismo estoy un poco perdido de como hacer estas llamadas y capturar la respuesta para que se ejecuten estos archivos. Es decir, lo que me gustaría es por ejemplo hacer una petición post con un parámetro un nombre de archivo y con eso accionar el archivo con ese nombre. Alguien me podía iluminar un poquillo?

Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Importa el archivo y ejecuta las funciones que quieres

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sí, por ejemplo, puedes enviarlo por una petición get

```
/mi-url/?archivo=nombre_archivo.extensión
```

y lo obtienes con

```
nombre_archivo = request.GET.get('nombre_archivo', None)
```

ahora, para ejecutar archivos lo haces con

```
exec(open(ruta/a/tus/scripts/nombre_archivo).read())
```